# Add additional parameters in tx_news title field

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase, tt-news

```
<n:link newsItem="{newsItem}" settings="{settings}"> {newsItem.title} </n:link>
```

The above code will generate a link to the details page . What I want to achieve is that , I want to add a new parameter &type to the news url. Can anybody please tell how I can implement this . Checked this http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Templating/ViewHelpers/LinkViewHelper.html . But I am getting an error

Answer (score 2):

The news link viewhelper inherits from the 'traditional' FLUID Viewhelper `\TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Link\PageViewHelper`. You can add the type as `additionalParams`:

```
<n:link additionalParams="{type : 4711}" newsItem="{newsItem}" settings="{settings}"> {newsItem.title} </n:link>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the info. I have already tried the same . But it throws an error like 
**#1237823695: Argument "additionalParams" was not registered**

Answer (score 0):

```
<n:link newsItem="{newsItem}" settings="{settings}" class="more" configuration="{additionalParams:'&fo=1'}">
    <f:translate key="more-link" />
</n:link>
```

checkout thils link:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/58844